# Converting datatypes and using it as an extension method for TestContext.DataRow

Tags: c#, mstest

I have an extension method for getting the data from xml using the DataRow.
Instead of writing line as TestContext.DataRow["Month"].ToString() .  I have written an extension method with type casting:

```
    public static T Get<T>(this DataRow row, string rowName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rowName)) throw new ArgumentNullException(rowName);
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        return (T)(converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(row[rowName].ToString()));
    }
```

My question is does the above extension method makes sense for getting the data from xml using type casting where i can give the lines as

```
1) string month = TestContext.DataRow.Get<string>("Month");

2) int monthVal = TestContext.DataRow.Get<int>("Month");
```

I have two different datatypes and each should give me the valid data and type when i use the above extension method. For me its working fine. But is that how i can do the type casting and make it as an extension method?

Comment: It's not clear what's your question if it's working fine

Comment: I'm not sure if i can i have ToString() in the return statement. Also, wanted to know if this above method follows the coding standards as I'm new to C#

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure if i can i have ToString() in the return statement.
>   Also, wanted to know if this above method follows the coding standards
>   as I'm new to C#

Yes, you can use [`TypeDescriptor.GetConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewtxwhzx(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a converter which uses `ConvertFromInvariantString` to convert the string to your target type.

The [`return` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return) is executed  last, so when the rest of the expression is evaluated. Of course `ToString` is needed because the method needs a `string` and not `System.Object`.

But instead of this extension the normal way to get your variables from a `DataRow` is the available [`Field`-extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string month = TestContext.DataRow.Field<string>("Month");
int monthVal = TestContext.DataRow.Field<int>("Month");
```

The difference is that this throws an `InvalidCastException` if the column is not a `string`/`int`, so you should know beforehand what it is. It cannot be both at the same time.

But you can always do:

```
string month = TestContext.DataRow["Month"].ToString();
int monthVal = int.Parse(month);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation